# How to calculate a series of equations?

Tags: tcl

I meet a question, if I get several equations from a file, for example :

```
na = 1.350
Lambda = 0.2
Seg = 2*na*Lambda
mag = 4
result = mag+Seg*3
```

how can I get the real value of the result?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what you need is a little parsing and a little mapping and, of course, some creative use of `eval`.

```
# Assume that the contents of the file is in a big string, $equations

array set vars {}
set map {}
foreach line [split $equations "\n"] {
    if {![regexp {^ *(\w+) *= *(.*)$} $line -> var exp]} {
        error "illegal line '$line'"
    }
    set vars($var) [expr [string map $map $exp]]
    puts "computed $var as $vars($var)"
    lappend map $var \$vars($var)
}
puts "result = $vars(result)"
```

Now the key bits of this are:

- `regexp {^ *(\w+) *= *(.*)$} $line -> var exp`

  Parses a line to extract the variable and the expression to compute to get the value of the variable.
- `expr [string map $map $exp]`

  Applies the current mapping to turn `$exp` into a Tcl expression, and evaluates the result as an expression. (Formally unsafe, but *really* convenient here!)
- `lappend map $var \$vars($var)`

  Updates the mapping transform to know how to read an appropriate variable. Basically, a `Lambda` will become `$vars(Lambda)` in future expressions.

Comment: Whoa. That is clever.

Comment: That's really amazing! Thanks!

Comment: Another question, this algorithm calculates result from top to down, but if these equations in the middle or later part of a large file,  how to find the  necessary variables or equations to get the value without calculating uncorrelated equations?

Comment: @Jimmy: both answers as of now depend on the variables being given values in the right order. To do the calculations if the equations aren't in the right order, you need to take note of which evaluations fail and redo them in a second iteration, repeating until every equation has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Donal Fellows' solution is excellent (with the possible caveat that an identifier that is a substring of another identifier can be problematic), but there are more ways to do this:

```
set equations {
    na = 1.350
    Lambda = 0.2
    Seg = 2*na*Lambda
    mag = 4
    result = mag+Seg*3
}
```

Convert this set of equations to a dictionary with the identifiers as keys:

```
% set expressions [dict create {*}[string map {= { }} $equations]]
na 1.350 Lambda 0.2 Seg 2*na*Lambda mag 4 result mag+Seg*3
```

In the dictionary values, prepend dollar signs to all identifiers (assumed to be all strings with only alphabetic characters)

```
dict for {ident expr} $expressions {
    dict set expressions $ident [regsub -all {([[:alpha:]]+)} $expr {$\1}]
}
```

Successively create variables corresponding to the identifiers, with values calculated from the expressions:

```
dict for {ident expr} $expressions {
    upvar 0 $ident var
    set var [expr $expr]
}

puts "Result: $result"
```

These steps can of course be consolidated for brevity:

```
dict for {ident expr} [dict create {*}[string map {= { }} $equations]] {
    upvar 0 $ident var
    set var [expr [regsub -all {([[:alpha:]]+)} $expr {$\1}]]
}
```

Documentation:
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)