# Equation Linear Algebra TCL

Tags: math, tcl

I need to solve this equation and find `t` :

```
4x + z − 2 = 0
```

With parameter:

```
x =− 1 − 2t
z = 1 + t
```

result:

```
4(− 1 − 2t) + (1 + t) − 2 = 0
t = − 5/7
```

How I can group my `t` values for this equation?

Comment: Take a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772787/how-to-calculate-a-series-of-equations

Comment: Thanks Peter , i didn't see this thread before my post , I tried but I failed , I will try with regexp for captured and multiplied every values I don't know ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can we rewrite the equations as lists of terms?

```
set terms {4x 1z -2}
set x {-1 -2t}
set z {1 1t}
```

If we have a command to split the terms into coefficient and variable parts (the variable part is the empty string if the term is a constant)

```
proc splitTerm term {
    scan $term %d%s
}
```

one command to multiply a list of terms with a factor

```
proc multiplyTerms {factor terms} {
    lmap term $terms {
        lassign [splitTerm $term] c v
        format %d%s [expr {$factor * $c}] $v
    }
}
```

one command to add terms and get one sum for constant terms and another for terms with a variable (at this stage the variable is assumed to be one and the same due to replacement)

```
proc addTerms terms {
    set constantsum 0
    set termsum 0
    foreach term $terms {
        lassign [splitTerm $term] c v
        if {$v eq {}} {
            incr constantsum $c
        } else {
            incr termsum $c
        }
    }
    list $constantsum $termsum
}
```

and finally a command to replace terms with variables with the term lists that those variables hold

```
proc replaceTerms terms {
    concat {*}[lmap term $terms {
        lassign [splitTerm $term] c v
        if {$v eq {}} {
            set c
        } else {
            multiplyTerms $c [set ::$v]
        }
    }]
}
```

Then we can replace the variables in the original list of terms

```
% set replaced [replaceTerms $terms]
-4 -8t 1 1t -2
```

And sum the list up:

```
% set result [addTerms $squashed]
-5 -7
```

This corresponds to the equation `-7t -5 = 0` which yields the solution `t = -5/7`.

Documentation:
[* (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm),
[eq (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[scan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/scan.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: Thank you Peter, I was very long of your solution, with my idea of using regexp . Pity that tcl is not known, I would like her to give you a lot of votes... Thanks